# Default screen saver after timed log out

Tags: mojave, screensaver

Can the default screen saver that kicks in after timed log out, be customised? Default is irritating 'Pong' type with computer's name bouncing around.

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Desktop and Screen Saver. Many to choose from.

[image]

Note: You won't find the `fff.` screensavers in your list. They're old and I'm not sure they work.